# Kubernetes Pod issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have one pod (A) running which has three replicas(A1,A2,A3). Suppose, one of my request is getting processed by pod A1. Before the completion of the process, pod A1 got down somehow. What will happen to the incomplete process? Will it start from where it failed or start again from the beginning or the process will get lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the process inside container, if the pod dies then your process also will die. So no, it won't start from where it failed it just dies. If you have http server in front of it then you gonna get 5** status code.